# Class that use another class

Tags: c++, qt, class

I have a problem with my classes.

I have two separate headers. Color.h and Painter.h:

1). Color.h

```
class Color{
       int number;
    public:
       void initialize();
       void change (Painter draw);
}
```

2). Painter.h

```
class Painter{
      Color a,b;
   public:
      void get();
      void draw();
}
```

My problem is, that i need to use Painter in class Color, and class Painter use Color. In Qt, i get a error that Painter is not a type. How can i fix this? What is solution for that problem?

Comment: You can make that happen by forward declaring one class in the other and use only pointers to the forward declared class. But if you have circular dependencies in such a simple case, consider changing the design of your software

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `Painter.h` you need to include `Color.h`, because you have objects of type Color.
But in `color.h` you can add a forward declaration for the `Painter` class:

```
class Painter;
class Color{
   int number;
public:
   void initialize();
   void change (Painter draw); //a forward declaration is enough for this
}
```

And the method `void change (Painter draw);` you will define it in the `color.cpp` and there you include `painter.h`

Comment: Don't you need to change `void change (Painter draw);` to `void change (Painter & draw);` for this to work?

Comment: @drescherjm I was thinking about that too, but it looks okay (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/553682/when-can-i-use-a-forward-declaration)

Comment: @Zlatomir: that is incorrect explanation: `because you don't construct an object there`. You do not need it, but not because of that as you do not construct the base class in the header either, yet you need it.